# How to derive impedance when permittivity is not scalar but tensor ?

Tags: electromagnetism

How is the impedance of anisotoropic material is defined?
How to derive the impedance when permittivity is not scalar but tensor.

Comment: I cannot understand why we need to set $[\epsilon]/\epsilon_0=[\mu]/\mu_0$ in the equation(3) of this paper(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3009756_A_Perfectly_Matched_Anisotropic_Absorber_for_Use_as_an_Absorbing_Boundary_Condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linear polarized plane wave the wave impedance is defined by the ratio of the E and H fields, here in an anisotropic  material it is defined as the same and you can always write it as $[\mu][\epsilon]^{-1}$.

If you set your coordinates along with the principal axes of say $[\mu]$ and diagonalize it then the matrix $[\epsilon]$ may or may not be diagonal. Here it is assumed that it *is* diagonal, see Equation (2).

The matching condition Equation (3) and hence (4) just means that along the principal axes the impedance, i.e., the ratio E/H is the same as that of the vacuum, and then from the proportionality of these diagonal matrices follows that matching will hold in any direction.

Comment: Thank you. I still cannot understand very well. E and H are perpendicular.  So I first thought $\mu_x {\epsilon_y }^{-1} = \mu_0 {\epsilon_0 }^{-1} $ for light traveling at z-direction. However, it is not true. Do you know why ?

Comment: I think the component $\mu_{x}$ refers to propagation along $x$.

Comment: Can you explain in more details why $\mu_x$ refers to propagation along x?

Comment: I cannot explain it because what I wrote was nonsense, sorry.